# In ATG, what is default caching for order repository?

Tags: atg, atg-dynamo

In atg what is default caching for order repository. 
As per the documentation it is simple(if my understanding is correct?).

Is it better to keep the order repository as simple, because lots of modification will happen for an order object. Is it better to keep it as distributed?

Answer (score -2):

It is always better to keep the cache mode simple. Distributed adds lots of communication between instances and this may add additional overhead for not a lot of value.

It can also be set to locked cache mode so that the order will be locked using the lock server mechanism in ATG. This will prevent different server instances (or even the same instance) from making changes to the order simultaneously. You can find more information about this here - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E41069_01/Platform.11-0/ATGRepositoryGuide/html/s1005lockedcaching01.html

Comment: Very dangerous statement: "It is always better to keep the cache mode simple". The correct answer to this question is 'it depends'. For example the CSC order repository cache overrides the commerce order repository cache conditions and is set to 'disabled'. So it all depends. @bated mentioned in a separate post about the same account being logged in on two different instances at the same time with concurrent changes being made. If both instances were using simple cache what will be persisted to the database? Caching is something that needs to be done carefully.

Comment: You're correct about the dangerous statement. I should have added that for most scenarios, "simple" cache mode should work. In case of CSC implementations, it could get more complicated. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Also, distributed caching has a big performance overhead, so be very careful. Locked caching is less of an overhead in terms of performance but it can result in deadlocks.  Any cache changes need to be thoroughly tested from a functional and performance perspective.